# Has the hardware in my modem gone bad?

Tags: router, hardware-failure, modem, dsl

I contacted CenturyLink about my modem recently and received useless and unrelated information.

The problem seems to be that the modem will no longer save settings, the web interface is unusable except in internet explorer for some reason, and the modem keeps resetting.

CenturyLink claimed it had to do with signal strength but I checked and it is currently between good and outstanding according to [this](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/16220).

All of the lights remain green even when it starts acting up and I lose internet and shortly before it crashes and reboots. Does anyone have any idea what is going on or what I can do to fix it? (Asking CenturyLink again is obviously not going to help.)

**Update 1**:

Accessing the syslog from the web interface causes a crash. After it reboots, the log looks like as follows:

```
01/01/1970  12:01:29 AM Ethernet    Ethernet client connected ,ip(192.168.0.2), mac(1c:6f:65:4c:6d:3b)
01/01/1970  12:01:38 AM Wireless    802.11 client connected ,ip(192.168.0.18), mac(d0:df:c7:c2:73:ca)
01/01/1970  12:01:41 AM System Event    Line 0: VDSL2 link up, Bearer 0, us=20128, ds=40127
01/01/1970  12:01:43 AM dhcp6s[2028]    dhcp6_ctl_authinit: failed to open /etc/dhcp6sctlkey: No such file or directory
01/01/1970  12:01:50 AM dhcp6s[2469]    dhcp6_ctl_authinit: failed to open /etc/dhcp6sctlkey: No such file or directory
01/01/1970  12:01:52 AM radvd[2306] poll error: Interrupted system call
01/01/1970  12:01:56 AM PPP Link    PPP server detected.
01/01/1970  12:01:56 AM PPP Link    PPP session established.
01/01/1970  12:01:56 AM PPP Link    PPP LCP UP.
01/01/1970  12:01:56 AM System Event    Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
06/05/2014  08:16:01 AM radvd[2511] poll error: Interrupted system call
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:03 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:04 AM System Event    Dead loop on virtual device tun6rd, fix it urgently!
06/05/2014  08:16:04 AM dhcp6s[3236]    dhcp6_ctl_authinit: failed to open /etc/dhcp6sctlkey: No such file or directory
06/05/2014  08:16:08 AM Wireless    802.11 client connected ,ip(192.168.0.7), mac(44:6d:57:c4:d7:08)
```

I also get it to crash on various other pages. I am guessing the web server is unstable.

Comment: Has the modem ever worked without problems?

Comment: When we first got it, back when it was running older firmware it seemed fine. When the latest firmware came out for it, the problems started showing up.

Comment: Sounds like a firmware problem.  Since DSL/Cable firmware is pretty much secret sauce, we can't without a shadow of a doubt, say what your problem is.  It sounds like a problem I had, but in my case, the problem was solved with the newer firmware.

Comment: Its strange because I don't hear other complaints about this firmware. I am wondering if they just lumped all of the modems together regardless of what hardware version they were and if that might have caused a few issues. I managed to get the firmware source (at least the original actiontec source if that might help)

Comment: I plan to start upgrading the firmware if anyone is interested in helping. Most of the packages used are pretty old. (For instance openssl)